# how can I test whether a cell is blank or actually a reference to a blank cell in Excel or Google Sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a large spreadsheet that's a mix of data cells, empty cells and cells referencing another sheet that also has a lot of empty cells.

I need to be able to distinguish between a "really" empty cell -- nothing in it -- and a reference to an empty cell in the other sheet.

I've tried a dozen things, but I can't find anything that doesn't treat the two as the same. I'm hoping to find something that works in both Excel and Google Sheets, but I'd be very happy if I find something that works in either one.

Comment: If sheet1!a1 is blank and you use `=sheet1!a1` on sheet2, you get a numerical zero in [tag:excel] but an apparently blank cell in [tag:google-spreadsheet].

Comment: So what are examples of these *'dozen things'* you have tried? Are you expecting us to reproduce each failed effort blindly so you can reply that you have already tried that method?

Comment: I haven't tried Ctrl-backtick, though I did try with and without quotes. I tried ISREF(), INDIRECT(), ISBLANK(), ISTEXT(), ISNONTEXT(), ISFORMULA(), ISERR(), ROW(), COLUMN() and probably some others either alone or in various combinations. Everything I tried just followed the reference and reported back on what was referred to. I wasn't taking very good notes, which was dumb. To be honest, I wasn't expecting folks here to investigate for me -- I kinda hoped somebody would know an answer. It looks like I'-'I maybe did, but I haven't had a chance to test it yet.

Comment: **I'-'I** has an answer below that works in Google Sheets and newer versions of Excel (but not mine). **Scott Craner** also has has an approach I think would work. It's more complicated but educational.

Answer (score 2):

to find truly empty in Excel:

```
=ISBLANK(A1)
```

Which will only return true if their is nothing, no formula or constants.

The you can use:

```
=A1=""
```

To test if it returning a blank.

So:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"NOTHING",IF(A1="","FORMULA RETURNING BLANK","VALUE"))
```

Note the order of operation here is important as `A1=""` will return TRUE if the cell is truly blank also.  So we want to rule out the first before asking the second.

A2 is blank and A3 has the formula `=""`

[image]

Comment: I think this returns the same value for a blank and a reference to a blank: "FORMULA RETURNING BLANK"

Comment: ... that comment was for Excel but it operates the same in Google Sheets.

Comment: However, it does differentiate between an empty cell and a reference to an empty cell. That's what I asked for, so thank you. (I tried to up vote but I'm not allowed.)